# Metasploit is stuck after sessions is open. Meterpreter doesn't show up

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux, metasploit

I'm experimenting with Metasploit and using it on my own machine.

I'm running Kali Linux on VirtualBox and trying to open a meterpeter session to my host Win 10 OS.

I generate a `reverse_tcp` payload, execute it on my host OS (Windows 10), and run `exploit/multi/handler` in Kali.

The session opens but meterpreter doesn't show up and nothing really happens. The metasploit is getting stuck at this point:
[Metasplilt is getting stuck at this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jezxN.png)
If I try to cancel the exploit with `Ctr+C` my whole machine freezes and I have to reboot it.

I think maybe the problems appear because the Kali Linux is a VM and I should somehow configure the VM box?

Ps *I hope my question is relevant to this site. I asked it on Security StackExchange, but it was removed as off topic.*